# How to get the document name from a SharePoint document library to a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am looking for a JavaScript to validate the input document name before uploading it to a SharePoint document library (in the edit form). So i want to get the particular document name to a variable. How can I get it?

```
attachment = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].firstChild; 
filename = attachment.data;
```

works fine with SP list to get the attachment name. But now I need to extract the file name from a document library edit form.

Please help?

BR